# Spring Web: Getting file from web context using Resource?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, resources

Is there a way to get a resource in a spring web application using a simple Resource? I am trying not to pass any context, and need to obtain a file from the WEB-INF/freemarker/email/ directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Since the `WEB-INF/freemaker/email` is *not* on the classpath, you need to pass `ServletContext`. As you mention `Resource`, you can use:

```
Resource resource = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, resourcePath);
```

Just don't pass the `ServletContext` to the service layer. Pass the `Resource` instead.

If you want to obtain the template from the classpath, place it there. That is, for example, in:

> WEB-INF/classes/freemaker/email

Then you can use `ClassPathResource`

Comment: specifically in this case, i am trying to get a freemarker template - even using ClasspathResource, and passing the full filename to the Freemarker Template i get exceptions.  I am just looking for the easiest way to obtain a ftl from the classpath.  You have any idea, or should i create a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware interface in your class and get access to ResourceLoader. That it's rather easy to use.

```
public class SomeService implements ResourceLoaderAware {
   private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

   public void doSomething() {
       Resource skin = resourceLoader.getResource("myfile.txt");
   }

    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

}
```